# First-order logic and Peano Arithmetic paradox

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I'm working through the [Stanford Introduction to Logic course](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/index.php), and seem to have proved that all natural numbers are equal to zero: `Ax.(x = 0)`. Obviously, this is incorrect, but I can't see how. My proof is by induction:

- Base case: `0 = 0` by premise
- Inductive case: `Ax.((x = 0) -> (s(x) = 0))`

  - If we assume that all natural numbers equal zero: `x = 0`
  - Then, since all natural numbers equal zero, the successor of any natural number also equals zero: `s(x) = 0` by simple substitution
- Conclusion: `Ax.(x = 0)`

I worked this up formally in Stanford's Fitch editor as well:

[image: formal proof]

Can anyone explain my error? Thank you.

Comment: Does that editor include a button that checks whether the proof is correct? The first Universal Introduction can't be right...

Comment: I believe the editor disallows invalid statements, but I'm not certain. Universal introduction allows a free variable to be explicitly quantified. So `x=0` implies `Ax.x=0`. In other words, we're not talking about a *specific* `x`, we're talking about all possible `x`'s.

Comment: It is absolutely  not true that  $x=0$ implies $Ax.x=0$! What's true is that $\vdash x=0$ implies $\vdash Ax.x=0$.  There's a huge difference.

Comment: I can't find the page describing Universal Introduuction, analogous to the page on Implication Introduction that you showed Carlos.

Comment: See http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/section.php?section=section_08_02, 4th slide: "Typically, UI is used on sentences with free variables to make their quantification explicit. For example, if we have the sentence hates(jane,y), then, we can infer ∀y.hates(jane,y)."

Comment: Aha. Note the fine print "where ν does not occur free in both φ and an active assumption"! Here that condition is violated, because $X=0$ is an active assumption.

Comment: So that's the error in the formal proof - as I suspected, an invalid application of UI. In the informal version: As Carlos tried to explain, in that proof by induction you're not allowed to assume $Ax.x=0$. That's simply not how induction works - if you're allowed to assume what you want to prove you can prove anything. In a proof by induction you're allowed to  assume $x=0$ ("for a specific $x$").

Comment: What kind of proof editor allows you infer that all x are equal to zero if some x is equal to zero (line 3)? Obviously a bug in the program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[David C. Ullrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/248223/david-c-ullrich) had the most useful answer, which I'll repeat here: The Universal Introduction on line 3 is invalid because `x` is free in the active assumption `x = 0`. Thank you for finding the error!

Comment: If you like an answer one thing you can do is click on the little arrow to "accept" it...

Answer (score 2):

When you write “If we assume that all natural numbers equal zero”, you are assuming the thing that you want to prove.

A proof by induction would be as follows:

- first you prove that the assertion holds when $x=0$ (as you did);
- then you prove that **if** the statement holds for $x$, **then** it also holds for $s(x)$.

And it's here where the problem lies, because one of the Peano axioms states that $0$ is **never** of the form $s(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming the thing that I want to prove. I think there's nothing wrong with that, because I then discharge that assumption by turning it into an implication, just as you suggest. See line 5 in the formal proof.

Comment: The fifth line of the formal proof is “$X=0\implies s(X)=0$”. How do you justify that?

Comment: It's spelled out in the proof. Line 5 introduces an implication based on lines 2 and 4: "if line 2 holds, then line 4 holds". This corresponds exactly to your second bullet.

Comment: But line 3 states that $(\forall X):X=0$, which, again, is the very thing that you want to prove.

Comment: Yes, but's that's legal in a proof: You can assume an arbitrary statement as long as you discharge that assumption by turning it into an implication.

Comment: Then your proof is **not** an inductive proof. And, no, you cannot assume arbitrary statements; if you do that, you will be able to “prove” everything.

Comment: See http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/implication_introduction.html: "If, by assuming φ, we can derive ψ, then we can derive (φ ⇒ ψ)."

Comment: I fully agree with that. But what you want to prove is $\varphi$, not that $\varphi\implies\psi$.

Comment: @brianberns What you are deriving this way is $(\forall x:\ x=0) \Rightarrow(\forall x:\ x=0)$

Comment: "Yes, I'm assuming the thing that I want to prove. I think there's nothing wrong with that, because I then discharge that assumption by turning it into an implication, just as you suggest. See line 5 in the formal proof." What? Line 5 reads $x=0\implies\dots$; if it resulted from discharging the assumption $\forall x.x=0$ line 5 would read $\forall x.x=0\implies\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

The informal  version is just not how  induction works. In proving $\forall x.x=0$ you're allowed to assume $x=0$, then you're required to prove $s(x)=0$. You're certainly not allowed to assume $\forall x.x=0$. Proofs by induction look sorta like they assume what they want to prove, but they don't, because of the difference between $x=0$ and $\forall x.x=0$.

That's if you're trying to prove $\forall x.x=0$. When Carlos pointed this out you mentioned something about Implication Introduction. But you didn't discharge the assumption!! As pointed out, you're allowed to assume $\forall x.x=0$ *if* you're trying to prove $\forall x.x=0\implies \forall x.x=0$.

The error, or at least one error, in the formal version is an invalid application of UI: The first UI is invalid because $X$ is free in an active assumption. (An informal version of that UI thing, as used by actual people in actual proofs: To prove $\forall xp(x)$, prove $p(x)$ **without** assuming anything about $x$.)

Comment: Not to mention, you might want to be careful about using UI at all.  Since the only $\forall$ intro rule is induction.

Comment: @DanielV I don't know what you're talking about. In the system in question induction is certainly not the only $\forall$ introduction rule.

Comment: If you can derive $p(x)$ then you can derive $\forall x. p(x)$ using only induction, you don't need UI, so the rules for UI can be derived from induction in such a system.

Comment: @DanielV Really? Say I can derive $p(x)$. Now how do I derive $\forall x(p(x)\implies p(s(x)))$?

Comment: In your proof for $p(x)$ replace $x$ with $s(x)$ (since it is generic) then weaken the claim to get $p(x) \to p(s(x))$ and induction shouldn't actually require the $\forall x$ in front of the $p(x) \to p(s(x))$ because induction is the $\forall$ intro rule.

Comment: Induction shouldn't require the $\forall x$. So how do you _state_ the principle of induction? Saying $(p(0)\land(p(x)\implies p(s(x)))\implies\forall x.p(x)$ is wrong...

Comment: It depends on how your logic treats free variables.  If the name of variables is shared between theorems but their meaning isn't, that is to say when $p(a)$ always means $\forall a.p(a)$, then the principle is simply stated as $$\dfrac{p(0),~p(x)\to p(s(x))}{\forall x.p(x)}$$ In a language where variable meanings cross over between theorems, $$\dfrac{p(0),~p(x) \vdash p(s(x))}{\forall x.p(x)}$$ or something similar works.  You can have induction be an axiom and use first order UI/UE, but then you aren't (directly) using peano arithemetic.  If you are using PA, induction is a rule of inference.

Comment: "If you are using PA, induction is a rule of inference" well of course it is; the issue is whether it's the only $\forall$ introduction rule. Your assertion that $UI$ is not an inference rule in the system in the OP iis of course simply not so. It may be that  we can concoct a system that allows us to do PA without UI. But _why_ would we want to do this? It's going to make everything more complicated! Because we certainly need UI in contexts other than PA. So now we have two proof systems, one for PA and one for everything else.

Comment: And that seems like a bad thing. The whole point to a formal proof system is that we have rules for checking whether a string of symbols iis  valid proof that depend only on the structure of the sequence of symbols, in particular rules that are independent of what the symbols might "mean". And now that's no longer so - whether a string is a valid proof depends on the intended interpretation. That's making the semantics, and a fairly fuzzy aspect of the semantics, part of the formal proof system.

Comment: Regardless of whether this program to  ban UI from PA is a good idea, another question about how it's supposed  to work:  How do you prove $\forall x(p(x)\land q(x))\implies \forall x(q(x)\land p(x))$?

Comment: I wasn't trying to start a fight.  I was just pointing out that in most arithmetic proof systems, UI isn't actually a rule of inference because it is subsumed by induction.  So the poster might want to double check that.  And there are way more than 2 proof systems.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic for example uses induction and not UI (in fact, doesn't even write out quantifiers) exactly because it makes things so simple, for the sake of consistency proofs for example.

Comment: As far as exactly showing a proof, logic systems are so diverse and a 500 comment character limit is so small as to make that not a reasonable thing to do here.  Roughly, you would assume $\forall x. px \land qx$ , vacuously establish $qy \land py \vdash qsy \land psy$ but without ever using $qy \land py$ instead using the original assumption, establish $q0 \land p0$ similarly, and that is all you need to invoke the induction inference and derive $\forall z. qz \to pz$.  Then apply deduction rule in whatever form the logic allows.